# Volume mount haproxy socket from HAProxy docker container

Tags: sockets, docker, docker-compose, haproxy

I want to give a peer container access to `/var/run/haproxy.sock`. Unfortunately, it throws an error when I try to do this through bind mounting with a named volume. Is is possible to share the **haproxy.sock** with other containers? I assume it is, so I wonder which piece I am missing here. Probably rights - but how to set them correctly?

```
worker1    | <7>haproxy-systemd-wrapper: executing /usr/local/sbin/haproxy -p /run/haproxy.pid -f /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -Ds
worker1    | [ALERT] 182/075644 (6) : Starting frontend GLOBAL: error when trying to preserve previous UNIX socket [/var/run/haproxy.sock]
worker1    | <5>haproxy-systemd-wrapper: exit, haproxy RC=1
```

I have the following config in **haproxy.cfg**:

```
global
    maxconn 8204
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
    stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
```

I use docker-compose to start my containers in swarm mode:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  haproxy:
    image: haproxy:1.7.7
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/home/ubuntu/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro"
      - "socket:/var/run/haproxy.sock:rw"
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 16479
        hard: 16479
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname==worker1

volumes:
  socket: {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Named volumes can only be *directories*, not single files. As a result, this line;

```
"socket:/var/run/haproxy.sock:rw"
```

Will attempt to mount a directory (the "socket" volume) at location `/var/run/haproxy.sock` inside the container.

If the location of "haproxy.sock" is configurable, you may try something like;

```
"socket:/my-haproxy-socket-directory"
```

(the socket itself would be located at `/my-haproxy-socket-directory/haproxy.sock` inside the container)